# Types of declaration methods Angular 6

Tags: angular, variables

I am having some confusion about below 2 types of declarations.

```js
filterabcData: abcHeader[] = [];
```

and

```js
searchedabcDetails = new abcHeader();
```

Anyone help me for this.

Comment: The first one is Array of type AsnHeader and the second one is an object of type AsnHeader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First one declaration says that filterabcData is an array having
   items of abcHeader type.
2. Second declaration is pointing that you are creating an object of abcHeader class  and storing it inside searchedabcDetails.

Comment: @user2609024 please accept my answer if you are able to understand.